# overwritting content of .txt file in php

Tags: php, file, file-put-contents

I need to overwrite the content of a .txt file when I browse a file in a page.I have written a php script for it.

Form is given below

```
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" maxlength="25"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
```

and PHP script is

```
$file1=$_FILES['file'];
$out = file_get_contents($file1);

$file2 = "molecule.txt";
$filehandle = fopen($file2, "a");
$file_contents = file($file1);
$count = count(file($file1));
file_put_contents($file2, "");
$newlineno = 0;
foreach ($file_contents as $line_num => $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'Standard orientation:') !== false) {
        for ($lineno = $line_num + 5; $lineno <= $count; $lineno++) {
            $line = $file_contents[$lineno];
            if (strpos($line, 'Rotational constants (GHZ):') != false) {
                break;
            }

            $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line);
            $split = explode(" ", $line);
            $symbol = $mapping[$split[2]];
            $x = $y = $z = '';

            if ($split[4] >= 0) {
                $x = ' ' . $split[4];
            } else {
                $x = $split[4];
            }
            if ($split[5] >= 0) {
                $y = ' ' . $split[5];
            } else {
                $y = $split[5];
            }
            if ($split[6] >= 0) {
                $z = ' ' . $split[6];
            } else {
                $z = $split[6];
            }

            $x = substr($x, 0, -3);
            $y = substr($y, 0, -3);
            $z = substr($z, 0, -3);
            $newlineno++;
            $newline = "ATOM\t" . $newlineno . "\t" . $x . "\t" . $y . "\t" . $z . "\t" . $symbol . "\n";

            fwrite($filehandle, $newline);
        }
    }
}


fclose($filehandle);

$lines = file($file2); 
$last = sizeof($lines) - 1 ; 
unset($lines[$last]); 

$fp = fopen($file2, 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, implode('', $lines)); 
fclose($fp); 

echo "File UPLOADED SUCESSFULLLy";

?>
<form method="POST" action="molecules.html"><br><br>
<p><input type="submit" name="structure" value="View file">
```

In `molecule.html` file contain code for displaying the content of `molecule.txt` file

But it is not overwriting the content of `molecules.txt` file.

Do I need anything more to add? Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: looks like data that belongs in a db

Comment: If you are trying to overwrite the content of file then open the file in write mode instead append mode.

Comment: Can you share your `molecule.html` file code?

Comment: code in molecule.html file are used for drawing 3d structure of chemical compound . It was a big file , how can I attach those file..... :(

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$filehandle = fopen($file2, "a"); // this mode means append content
```

use

```
$filehandle = fopen($file2, "w"); //this mode means write file by over writing the previous content
```

Comment: it will erasing the content of molecule.txt file

Comment: i want to overwrite the content of molecule.txt file .

Comment: yes this remove the old content in the molecule.txt and add your new content to the file, as per my knowledge that is what overwriting means

Comment: Ya ofcourse... But it will not writing new content in molecule.txt file

Comment: Where do you wish to write your new content then?

Comment: need to write in molecule.txt file itself

Comment: as per your code you are doing the same, what you are doing in your code is appending the data to your existing data, as your title of the question says that you want to overwrite the content i suggested you to clean the file and then add new content to it, i.e the file molecules.txt

Comment: as per your requirement you need to add new content to the existing file, my solution is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
$filehandle = fopen($file2, "w+");
```

//w+ : Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Note - using fopen in 'w' mode will NOT update the modification time (filemtime) of a file like you may expect. You may want to issue a touch() after writing and closing the file which update its modification time. This may become critical in a caching situation.

I am suggesting two approach

**Approach - 1** (File handling, simplest method; considering you're not doing any logical operation or string matching from the content, being read out)

molecules.html - Page containing form to upload file

```
<form method="POST" action="fileOverwrite.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

fileOverwrite.php - File for overwriting logic/script

```
<?php
$file1      = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$out        = file_get_contents($file1);
$file2  = "molecule.txt";
$filehandle= fopen($file2, "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($filehandle, $out);
fclose($filehandle);
echo "File UPLOADED SUCESSFULLLY";
?>
<form method="POST" action="molecules.html">
    <br/ ><br />
    <input type="submit" name="structure" value="View file" />
</form>
```

**Approach - 2** (matches your requirement, where you're doing some string search)

molecules.html - Page containing form to upload file

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

fileOverwrite.php - File for overwriting logic/script

```
<?php
// Capture the file's temp path and name
$file1  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

// Reads entire file into a string
$out    = file_get_contents( $file1 );

// Target file
$file2  = "molecule.txt";

// Open file for reading and writing
$filehandle = fopen( $file2, "w+" );

//Reads entire file into an array
$file_contents = file( $file1 );

$count = count( file( $file1 ) );

// Write a string to a file
file_put_contents( $file2, $file_contents );

$newlineno = 0;
foreach ($file_contents as $line_num => $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'Standard orientation:') !== false) {
        for ($lineno = $line_num + 5; $lineno <= $count; $lineno++) {
            $line = $file_contents[$lineno];
            if (strpos($line, 'Rotational constants (GHZ):') != false) {
                break;
            }

            $line   = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $line );
            $split  = explode( " ", $line );
            $symbol = $mapping[$split[2]];
            $x = $y = $z = '';

            if ($split[4] >= 0) {
                $x = ' ' . $split[4];
            } else {
                $x = $split[4];
            }

            if ($split[5] >= 0) {
                $y = ' ' . $split[5];
            } else {
                $y = $split[5];
            }

            if ($split[6] >= 0) {
                $z = ' ' . $split[6];
            } else {
                $z = $split[6];
            }

            $x = substr($x, 0, -3);
            $y = substr($y, 0, -3);
            $z = substr($z, 0, -3);

            $newlineno++;
            $newline = "ATOM\t" . $newlineno . "\t" . $x . "\t" . $y . "\t" . $z . "\t" . $symbol . "\n";

            // Binary-safe file write
            fwrite($filehandle, $newline);
        }
    }
}

// Close open file pointer
fclose($filehandle);

$lines = file($file2); 
$last   = sizeof($lines) - 1; 
unset($lines[$last]);

$fp = fopen($file2, 'w+');
fwrite( $fp, implode( '', $lines ) );
fclose($fp);

echo "File UPLOADED SUCESSFULLLY";
?>

<form method="POST" action="molecules.html">
    <br/ ><br />
    <input type="submit" name="structure" value="View file" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your response I have tried it.....But it doesnot updating content of molecule.txt file

Comment: Do you want a) new content to be added at the end of existing content while keeping the old as it is or b) replace old content with new one removing old one

Comment: I've updated this with entire code which is short as well. You may try this. It fulfils option b.